# Is it possible to specify the build environment of Travis CI with a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

Can I specify the build environment of Travis CI with a Dockerfile?

For example, here is my Dockerfile

```
From continuumio/miniconda
RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y  lcov 
...some other scripts...
```

Travis allows us to specify OS versions etc but I do not know if we can have a server with anaconda preinstalled from a Dockerfile, instead of writing the installation script within .travis.yml.  Note that this request is different from using Docker as a service as explained in the official travis document: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass configuration to your Travis CI job is to use the `.travis.yml` file. It is not possible to use neither Dockerfile nor any other configuration file to pass your environment setup.

However you can use Build Import [1] feature where you will be able to control your Travis CI configuration within multiple files, this still requires YAML syntax within.

[1] https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-config-imports

Mustafa

--

Travis CI staff